# How do I prevent stretching in the image texture here?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor, seams

I am currently following Blender Guru's Anvil modeling tutorials, however, when marked the part that is at the base of the horn, the image texture became stretched. How do I fix this?

[image: Example of stretching]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the textures are not packed in your blend file, i just checked the UV's. I noticed some stretching in the UV's in that area. Ideally, it should be blue indicating that it is not stretched.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, under *Advanced*, switch the *UV Smooth* to *Keep Corners*:

[image]